# How to position a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to put a `ListView` at the top of my activity, and something else on the bottom without the `ListView` "swallowing" the widgets on the bottom? I tried this (with the "something else" being a `RelativeLayout` with a single button in it), but it doesn't work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I looked for some hints [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/), which is very useful, but doesn't say anything about `ListView`s. I can place widgets above a `ListView` without problem, but not below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout as the root layout then position the ListView with `layout_above` and the Button with `layout_alignParentBottom`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now the list doesn't swallow the button, but if the list is shorter than the available space, it shows directly above the button instead of the top. Is it possible to make the list appear on the top but still not swallow the button?

Comment: @petersohn - set the height of the ListView to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is already answered several times on SO...

Change your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And is nesting views unnecessarily

Comment: I just copied the RelativeLayout from your code, I thought you were going to replace that part with whatever you have that may have more things inside... that's why I kept it